# Not able to start the SAP BOBJ server

Tags: business-objects, sap-bw

I have installed SAP BOBJ server in Portable SSD(External Disk) with the help of SAP consultant. But, when I start the service(BI Agent Windows Service), showing status as "Running" for few seconds, but not started. Where to check the server logs? I am seeing below path under "Path to Executable" in BI Agent service.

**H:\bobj_installation\AdminConsole\Agent\CreateService.exe //RS//BOEXI40Agent**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some documentation, found solution.

1) First need to start the "Server Intelligent Agent" Service under Services.

2) Start the "Apache Tomcat for BI 4" service under Services.